# How to block internet access for OpenVPN clients and restrict traffic to VPN network? (Installed with openvpn-install)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, iptables, firewall, openvpn

I setup an OpenVPN server using [openvpn-install](https://github.com/Angristan/OpenVPN-install). I would like clients to be able to connect to the VPN server, but any traffic aimed towards the internet instead of the VPNs local network should be blocked.

I have seen many solutions proposing adding `push` commands to `server.conf` requesting that clients use their own network for internet traffic by default, however these requests can be ignored by clients - this is not something I want.

I only want VPN clients to be able to access the local VPN network (at `10.8.0.0/24`), all other traffic should be rejected by the VPN server and clients should user their own networks for it.

How can I forcibly block internet traffic from VPN clients?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved through the use of `iptables`, by blocking traffic headed from the OpenVPN network interface to the network interface with internet access.

[openvpn-install](https://github.com/Angristan/OpenVPN-install) creates a few `iptables` configuration files that manage the rules for you.

The following instructions assume that:

- `tun0` is the network interface of OpenVPN
- `eth0` is the network interface with internet access

## Cleaning Initial Rules

First, we need to disable the current rules loaded by openvpn-install by running the following command:

```
systemctl stop iptables-openvpn
```

## Configuration Files

Note: using `DROP` instead of `REJECT` is also valid, it just doesn't return an error to the VPN client. See the [iptables man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/iptables) for more info.

### add-openvpn-rules.sh

In `/etc/iptables/add-openvpn-rules.sh`, change the line from:

```
iptables -I FORWARD 1 -i tun0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
```

to:

```
iptables -I FORWARD 1 -i tun0 -o eth0 -j REJECT
```

### rm-openvpn-rules.sh

In `/etc/iptables/rm-openvpn-rules.sh`, change the line from:

```
iptables -D FORWARD -i tun0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
```

to:

```
iptables -D FORWARD -i tun0 -o eth0 -j REJECT
```

## Applying The Changes

Run the following command and your changes should be saved and in effect:

```
systemctl start iptables-openvpn
```

## Split Tunneling

Pushing routes to the VPN clients can then be used to request they send internet traffic through their own network. Here are the lines I added to my OpenVPN `server.conf` file to achieve this (my VPN network is at `10.8.0.0/24`):

```
push "route 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0 vpn_gateway"
push "route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 net_gateway"
```